# Google Sheets Checkbox vs. Tickbox

Tags: google-sheets, localization, data-validation

Sometimes, I've seen Checkbox but I've also seen Tick Box. Does anyone know what's going on?

[image: Checkbox vs Tickbox]

Comment: Add more detail about how you took the screenshots. Are you using the same device and web browser?

Comment: Both were on the same device and browser (Chrome). The main difference was one was with my personal Google account and the other with my work one (G Suite?)

Comment: All the relevant details should be included in the question. Please [edit] the question to add the relevant environment variables like name and version of the operative system and web browser used account language settings. P.S. You might be using different English variants, i.e, English (United States) and English (United Kingdom). P.S. Question review is done only considering the question content. This question was reviewed b/c it was bumped by Community user (bot).

Answer (score 0):

It's all the same. The reason is the language difference of each spreadsheet.

> A **checkbox** (**check box**, **tickbox**, **tick box**) is a GUI widget that permits the user to make a binary choice, i.e. a choice between one of two possible mutually exclusive options.
>
> **https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkbox**

In Japanese it looks like this:

[image: 0]

---

You can switch to any language here:

[image: 0]

Comment: I actually thought this might have been it. However, I double checked both accounts and verified they were both set to the same locale and language settings (United States and English)

Comment: in any case, this is it. English languages just differ based on the country. Also, G-Suit accounts are tricky one coz they belong in the domain which can be set up for different English language

Answer (score 0):

Google offers several English variants, like English (United States), English (United Kingdom), etc., for their apps UI. Some UI elements names are exactly the same but others aren't like occurs on this case.

Another case is the Gmail, on English (United States) there is a `Trash` while in English (United Kingdom) there is a `Bin` but both shows the deleted email messages.

The instructions to change the Google account language are on [Change language](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32047?hl=en). Once you select English, pay attention to the next dialog as it list all the English variants that Google offers for the Google apps UI.

[image]

NOTE: The setting that you choose applies to all the Google apps UIs, there isn't a way to set the language to be used on an app by app way, but some apps like Google Sheets could have a setting for certain features like the language to be used for Google Sheets functions.

Answer (score 0):

When you put in a checkbox, it will display in the cell or range of cells, which you have painted, and it will be unchecked. If you see in the formula bar, the cell has a value of FALSE that refers you can link to this checkbox cell without formula.